# How can I center an image so that it only shows the middle of it?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap. I have 4 columns, each containing a large image. How can I only display the center of the image and have it re-size responsively?

Here is what I currently have: http://catsarecrits.com/

CSS:

```
.item {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 item" id="steam"><img src="assets/img/steam.jpg"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3 item" id="twitter"><img src="assets/img/twitter.png"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3 item" id="gplus"><img src="assets/img/g+.jpeg"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3 item" id="contact"><img src="assets/img/contact.png"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I found this example of what I want if I didn't describe it well: http://www.beastsmc.com/
If you view the background image of each server, it is large, but they display only the center.

I have tried using the img-responsive and center-block classes, but they didn't work.

Thank you very much!

Comment: It would probably be easier to do this with a background image with its `background-position` set to center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they're using it like everyone else, with

```
img{background-position:50%}
```

their exact code:

```
.index > a#creativeLink span.image {
    background-image: url('../i/creative.jpg');
}
```

in your case, it would translate to something like this:

```
#steam{background:url(assets/img/steam.jpg) no-repeat 50%; background-size:cover}
```

Comment: because your html is empty. add something (whatever) and then color:transparent so the columns get their size. Also, remember in BS to add a container div enclosing the row, whether it's container or fluid-container

Answer (score 0):

```
<center> your code <center/>
```

Comment: The `<center>` tag is [deprecated in HTML5](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp). Not recommended!

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--Do try this
(set this class to you image)-->

.img-align {
    margin: 50% 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```